# Hector_mapping live mapping?

Tags: navigation, mapping, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @All,
does anybody here knows, if it is possible to do live-mapping with hector_mapping? The tutorial shows only with recorded bag. I tried saving with map_server but without success. When trying geotiff_saver(?) it seems to save every second a very small file, but the files can not be opened. Any hint is helpfull.

Thanks a lot

Michael from Berlin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65493/hector_mapping-live-mapping?/) by [mharms](https://answers.ros.org/users/4636/mharms/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, this is possible and the intended use. Just run a real robot instead of the bag. If you see that map in rviz everything worked fine. Why you are not able to save the map is another question. You'll need to provide more details on what you actually did.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mharms](https://answers.ros.org/users/4636/mharms/) on 2013-06-19**:
Here more details:After running our robot:roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch, I can see the map developing. Then trying rostopic pub syscommand std_msgs/String "savegeotiff"  I only find very small files, that I cant open.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-06-19**:
I'm not sure how the hector system is setup, but if you just want to have a occupancy map (not geotiff), once you can see the map, the map_saver should work.